# Php get_result() and fetch_assoc() alternative

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on writing a PHP backend program, but my program doesn't work because PHP doesn't support the `get_result()` and `fetch_assoc()` function.

How can I rewrite the code so that they can work in the same way as this function?

```php
public function storeUser($userLoginID, $password) {                        

    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"];
    $salt = $hash["salt"];
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO hkcheung.users(unique_id,userLoginID,encrypted_password,salt,created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $uuid, $userLoginID, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM hkcheung.users WHERE userLoginID=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $userLoginID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $users = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $users;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why doesn't it work ? what is the error you receive?

Comment: It should work, but the host do not support get_result() function, the php version is not new enough. The host is from my university,I cannot upgrade it myself and I am forced to adjust me code to cope with it. But I am new to php.

Comment: try mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of $result->fetch_assoc(); and  mysqli_stmt_get_result ( $result ) instead of          $result = $stmt->get_result();

Comment: how about get_result() statement? The php program can't run once it reached the       $result = $stmt->get_result();

Comment: I have editted my comment read it above

Comment: I have tried, modified $result = $stmt->get_result() into $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt), but still this statement cannot run

Comment: What is PDO? I think I can try.(Sorry, i am very new to PHP. Just started to learn it 2 days ago.)

Comment: imo, Use PDO. All these problems just go away. imo, you are working harder.

Comment: @Philip [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) is PHP Data Objects, a way of abstracting away from the database you’re querying. You seem to be using the MySQLi extension to connect to your database; I agree with the others: switch to PDO instead. It’s very easy and you’ll only have to change a few function calls here and there. With PDO, you’d instead do `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to fetch the results as an associative array.

Comment: Also, if your university host is still running PHP 5.2 (and they must be, since `mysqli::get_results()` has been available since 5.3.0), they **seriously** need to update. PHP 5.2 has been [unsupported and deprecated for five and a half years](http://php.net/eol.php), and if you can, you should tell your IT department that they’re running some fairly big security risks by having their servers run such old, outdated versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

add below function to your php file

```
function get_result( $Statement ) {
    $RESULT = array();
    $Statement->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
        $PARAMS = array();
        while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
        $Statement->fetch();
    }
    return $RESULT;
}
```

and  at the `get_result` line, change it to

```
$result =  $this->get_result($stmt);
```